# Deal with EOFError while downloading files from server

Tags: python-2.7, ftp, ftplib, eoferror

**Use Case:**

Dowload hundred of thousands of xmls files (size from bytes to 50 mb/file) structured like this /year-month/year-month-day/hours/files with ftplib.
So i loop through each hour folder for a given day and for each one i store all the filenames with ftp.nlst(), then i loop through each filename and i donwload the concerned file like this.

```
with open(local_file, 'wb') as fhandle:
    try:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)
    except EOFError:
        try:
            fhandle.close()
            os.remove(local_file)
            ftp = ftplib.FTP()
            ftp.connect(self.remote_host,self.port, timeout=60)
            ftp.login(self.username, self.passwd, acct="")
            ftp.cwd(self.input_folder + '/' + subdir)
            try:
                with open(local_file, 'wb') as fhandle:
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write, 8192)
            except:
                self.log.error('i give up !!!')
```

**Expected:**

For each day given as input folder, download all the concerned xml files

**what i get:**

EOFError

**What i already tried:**

- I have gone though all possible posts about the subject on
  stackoverflow and the net in general.
- i have tried to close and open
  a ne connection for each subfolder in the hour folder.
- It doesn't seem to be one specific file that is causing the problem. It is definitely not the first one. i get this `EOFError` while downloading files with `ftp.retrbinary()`. It is related to the fact that i download hundred of thousands of xmls files, because i have tested the script with 2000 files and i didn't got any exceptions but with around 287000 files i get it always. And what i don't understand is that the script downloads each time the same amount/number of xml files, around 159 000 and it is always
- I have tried to play with the buffersize in

  `ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write,4096)`

**Question:**

it may be that i have missed something?
How to handle this EOFError to continue downloading all my files...and without loosing my sanity.

Comment: When do you get the `EOFError`? On the first file already? Or on subsequent files? On what statement? Show us exception stack trace.  - It's not clear from your question, how exactly does your problem relate to the *"Download hundred of thousands of xmls files"*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It doesn't seem to be one specific file causing the problem. It is definitely not the first. i get this `EOFError` while downloading files with `ftp.retrbinary()`. Sorry i have totally forgot about the stacktrace, i will post one monday. It is related to the fact that i download hundred of thousands of xmls files, because i have tested the script with 2000 files and i didn't got any exceptions but with around 287000 files i get it always. And what i don't undertsnad is that the script donlowds each time the same amoun/number of xml files, around 159 000 and it is always

Comment: All that information should have been in your question from the very first moment. Please edit it in.

Comment: Did you check server-side log? There may be a session time or data volume limit on the server side.

Comment: good idea! i will check and come back to you.

Comment: Can you actually download all the files using a standalone FTP client, using a single connection, running on the same machine as your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for my problem. Instead of opening a connection for each sub-folder, i now open a connection for each file to be downloaded. It is less performant, but i get to pass this `EOFError`.
I also found out that the FTP server which i want to download files from have restrictions for example on the number of parallel connections or how long a connection may last.