# Download files from FTP server: Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Tags: python, ssh, download, ftp, paramiko

I want to download files from an FTP server (I have installed a test vsftpd server on Linux 14.04 lts, Python version 2.7.13, Paramiko version 2.2.1) using the following code (I'm not posting all of it, only where the exception is raised)

```
import datetime
import socket
import paramiko
import os
import shutil

today = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
formattedtime = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')
destination = '/home/path/TestDir-%s' % formattedtime

if not os.path.exists(destination):
   os.mkdir(destination)

def file_download(hostname, username, hostport, password):
    rsa_private_key = r"~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    def agent_auth(transport, username):

    try:
        ki = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(rsa_private_key)
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Failed loading {} {}'.format(rsa_private_key, e)        
    agent = paramiko.Agent()
    agent_keys = agent.get_keys() + (ki,)
    if len(agent_keys) == 0:
        return
    for key in agent_keys:
        print 'Trying ssh-agent key{}'.format(key.get_fingerprint().encode('hex'), )
        try:
            transport.auth_publickey(username, key)
            print '... success!'
            return
        except paramiko.SSHException, e:
            print '... failed!', e
    password = password  # This is used when password is used to login
    host = hostname
    username = username
    port = hostport
    paramiko.util.log_to_file("/home/path/Desktop//filename.log")
    hostkeytype = None
    hostkey = None
    files_copied = 0
    try:
        host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
    except IOError:
        try:
            host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/ssh/known_hosts'))
        except IOError:
            print '*** Unable to open host keys file'
            host_keys = {}
    if hostname in host_keys:
        hostkeytype = host_keys[hostname].keys()[0]
        hostkey = host_keys[hostname][hostkeytype]
        print 'Using host key of type %s' % hostkeytype
    try:
        transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
        transport.start_client()
        agent_auth(transport, username)
        if not transport.is_authenticated():
            print 'RSA key auth failed! Trying password login...'
            transport.auth_password(username=username, password=password)
        else:
            ssftp = transport.open_session()
        ssftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
        print ssftp
    except Exception as qw:
        print "asdasd {}".format(qw)
```

But i get always this exception:

> Error reading SSH protocol banner

Here is the stacktrace:

```
DEB [20170623-17:28:22.595] thr=1  paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x2806c910L DEB [20170623-17:28:22.595] thr=1 paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.1.2 
DEB [20170623-17:28:22.596] thr=1  paramiko.transport: Banner: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2) DEB [20170623-17:28:22.596] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Banner: 530 Please login with USER and PASS. 
ERR [20170623-17:28:24.599] thr=1  paramiko.transport: Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner ERR [20170623-17:28:24.600] thr=1 paramiko.transport: Traceback (most recent call last): 
ERR [20170623-17:28:24.600] thr=1  paramiko.transport: File "/balh/blah/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1749, in run ERR [20170623-17:28:24.600] thr=1  paramiko.transport:     self._check_banner() 
ERR [20170623-17:28:24.600] thr=1  paramiko.transport: File "/balh/blah/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1897, in _check_banner 
ERR [20170623-17:28:24.600] thr=1  paramiko.transport: raise SSHException('Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e)) 
ERR [20170623-17:28:24.600] thr=1  paramiko.transport: SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

I have already tried to increase the `self.banner_timeout = 60` in `transport.py`, like suggested in some tickets but without success.

Comment: Please fix the code formatting in your post

Comment: thnx. Done! it must be now better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Banner: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2) ...

This means you are connecting to an FTP server.

> SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

This means you are expecting an SSH server not an FTP server.

The reason for this confusion is that you are assuming that SFTP is just like  FTP, but its not. These are completely different protocols. SFTP is file transfer on top of SSH while FTP is the 30+ year old protocol described in [RFC959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt). And FTPS (not SFTP) is SSL support added to this old protocol.

To access an FTP or FTPS server you can use `ftplib` in Python.
To access your server with SFTP use port 22 (ssh) not port 21 (ftp) as target port, provided that there is an SSH server at this port which also allows SFTP.

Comment: Your answer is very much appreciated. I have already tested `ftplib` before searching desperately for an alternative until i have found `paramiko`...which like you said is not what i thought it would be.

The problem that i have encountered with ftplib is pretty good described in this ticket. So feel free to suggest a possible solution/alternative if you have the time for it. [Deal with EOFError while downloading files from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934576/deal-with-eoferror-while-downloading-files-from-server)

Comment: @sdikby: I doubt that the problem you described in the ticket is related to ftplib but it is mostly likely overload of the server, limits at the server or similar. Sadly, you never followed up the comments there which asked for server side logs and if you have similar problems with a standalone FTP client.